# Grouped the rows by harvest week and get the sum in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a list in C# with the following data,

The structure of the list is,

```
HarvestWeekDate   HarvestDate    Quantity
1/2/2012          1/2/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/2/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/3/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/4/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/5/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/6/2012       100
1/2/2012          1/6/2012       100

1/9/2012          1/9/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/10/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/10/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/11/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/12/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/13/2012       100
1/9/2012          1/13/2012       100
```

I want to group by Harvest Week Date then get the distinct harvest dates from the harvest week group then sum the quantity of the havest week by distinct harvest 
dates.

Thanks & Regards,
Faisal Nasir

---

Is there any way I can achieve this using Lambda Expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is named harvestData here is a LINQ query that will give you the results you are looking for:

```
var groupedData = (from d in harvestData
                   group d by new { 
                        HarvestWeekDate = d.HarvestWeekDate, 
                        HarvestDate = d.HarvestDate } into g
                   select new { 
                      HarvestWeekDate = g.Key.HarvestWeekDate, 
                      HarvestDate = g.Key.HarvestDate, 
                      TotalQuantity = g.Sum (w => w.Quantity) }
                  );
```

I would suggest taking a look at the [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Lambda Expression," you mean the Linq extension methods:

```
var groupedData = harvestData.GroupBy (d => new { d.HarvestDate, d.HarvestWeekDate })
                             .Select  (g => new { HarvestWeekDate = g.Key.HarvestWeekDate, 
                                                  HarvestDate = g.Key.HarvestDate, 
                                                  TotalQuantity = g.Sum (w => w.Quantity) });
```